# Tomcat warning: The executor associated with thread pool [http-apr-8080] has not fully shutdown

Tags: java, tomcat, threadpool, apr

I am running a web application using tomcat8 and jdk1.8 on a linux server.

When I shut down tomcat I get the following warning message:

```
WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.shutdownExecutor The executor associated with thread pool [http-apr-8080] has not fully shutdown. Some application threads may still be running
```

Note: I only get this warning when I shutdown tomcat, not when I undeploy my application.

How can I "fix" this warning so that the message won't appear.
I do a thread dump using Jstack while the application is running and I see several http-apr-8080-exec threads.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was caused as a result of shutting down tomcat while the instance was still "attached" to the Elastic Load Balancer.
The ELB has a feature called `Connection Draining` which, by default, is set to 300 s.
You can disable connection draining or just remove the instance from the ELB before shutting down tomcat in order to not get the warning message.

Answer (score 1):

We have to Stop any application before we shutdown the tomcat because the servlets might serve the requests during shutdown process.

**Reference:** https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/tomcat-the-definitive/0596003188/ch01s02.html

Please check the section- **Restarting Tomcat**
It says that 
*"The Java Servlet Specification also dictates that, on shutdowns, servlet containers must wait for each servlet to finish serving all requests that are in progress or wait a container-specific timeout duration before taking servlets out of service. For Tomcat 4, that timeout duration is a maximum of a half-second per servlet. When a servlet misbehaves and takes too long to finish serving requests, it's up to Tomcat to figure out that the servlet has taken too long and to forcibly take it out of service so that Tomcat can shut down. This processing takes time, though, and slows Tomcat's own shutdown processing."*

**Best Practice:**
When you Stop the application from tomcat, the servlets are out of service. Hence you will not face this issue.

Please follow the process of stopping the application first and shutdown the tomcat server.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure that this is true...that you have to undeploy all web applications before stopping tomcat. I will look into this and update if I find concrete evidence.

Comment: i corrected the answer. I hope that it will be usefull